# Sensortag20 Program Crashes connecting to bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm trying to modify this project from android studio 2 but when I try to run the app from Android 4.4.2 and connect to a bluetooth device, it gives these error messages.

```
06-02 14:51:30.126 12669-12669/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ti.ble.sensortag, PID: 12669
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.<init>(BluetoothDevice.java:564)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter.java:418)
at com.example.ti.ble.common.BluetoothLeService.disconnect(BluetoothLeService.java:635)
at com.example.ti.ble.sensortag.MainActivity.onConnect(MainActivity.java:320)
at com.example.ti.ble.sensortag.MainActivity.onDeviceClick(MainActivity.java:379)
at com.example.ti.ble.sensortag.ScanView$1.onItemClick(ScanView.java:205)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The project can be found here [SensorTag20 Project](https://git.ti.com/sensortag-20-android?OrderOnline=More%20Info&TICOM_AUTHLEVEL=3&TICOM_VALIDATE_INPUT=1&TICOM_AUTHLEVEL=3&TICOM_VALIDATE_INPUT=1). How do I fix these problems?

Comment: The SensorTag uses Bluetooth LE which is not supported in Android 4.2.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, just realised that my device is actually running Android 4.4.2. Will ammend now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I just needed to restart the device everytime I reprogram it.